# Equally horizontally spacing 3 labels

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I'm currently writing an app in Appcelerator Titanium. I have three labels that I would like to evenly space horizontally.

Here's an example

```
Label 1     |     Label 2
```

The middle label will always be a bar but the other two labels will vary in size. Right now, I have the bar and the second label in a view attached to the right side of the screen and the first label attached to the left, but if the left label is fairly small, this looks bad.

I can't keep them all in one text field because the middle label is styled differently.

How can I properly lay these elements out so they are evenly spaced horizontally?

Comment: Why dont you just add the interfacebuilder and set the left textalign to left and the right to right?

Comment: @Arbitur This is a titanium app. I don't believe I can use interfacebuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options, but one quick one could be to use a [StyledLabel](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/styledlabel) which is like a very light version of a webview which allows you to render Text using HTML / CSS, this would let you consolidate your labels into  one label, for example:

```
var StyledLabel = require('ti.styledlabel');
var label = StyledLabel.createLabel({
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE || 'auto', 
    html: '<span>Label 1</span>     |     <span>Label 2</span>'
});
```

You can edit the `span` tags with custom CSS to fit what you need.

**Alternatively**, try using percentage layouts and careful use of the textAlignment property.

```
var container = Ti.UI.createView({width : "100%", layout: "horizontal" });
var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Label 1",
    width : "33%",
    textAlign : Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT
});
var label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: "|",
    width : "33%",
    textAlign : Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
});
var label3 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Label 2",
    width : "33%"
    textAlign : Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT
});
container.add(label1);
container.add(label2);
container.add(label3);
```

Comment: I decided to go with this because of the alternative section. I don't think using html in my native app would be a good choice. However, the second option worked wonders. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Titanium.UI.ListItem` [API Doc link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListItem)

Add your label as an item, put your minimal height / width and use also `Ti.UI.SIZE` as a fixed size, IT will automagically set a size for the element that is relevent to the content.

Don't Forget to set an horizontal layout for your view

PS: i didn't test this method, it is just a quick answer, hope it will help you ;)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the layout property of the view that hold all your three label as 'horizontal'.
First add the first label to the view and then add second label with 'X' amount of left property and then add 3rd label with same 'X' value of left property.

Hope it will meet your requirement.